# Python Libraries for Exact (Weighted) Maximum Independent Sets

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to get some approximation ratios for the Maximum Independent Set Problem and so I need some exact solutions !

I've found libraries written in C++  (i.e https://github.com/iPapatsoris/Maximum-Independent-Set)
but wondered if there were any directly in Python. I know of the `networkx' maximal indepedent set function but these are only approximations.

I realise it's far from the most efficient language to use but I'm only solving small  Erdős–Rényi graphs (N<20).

In addition to this, are there any libraries that solve this for the weighted problem, where some nodes matter more than others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only python library I could find:

https://github.com/pchervi/Graph-Coloring/blob/master/Coloring_MWIS_heuristics.py

I haven't checked that it works correctly however.

I've been using KaMIS instead, which is a C++ implementation.

https://github.com/KarlsruheMIS/KaMIS