# Finding minimum no. of sub-list from the list(l2) which have maximum elements in a other list(l1). Answer should contain least no. of sub-list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, recursion, dynamic

Get the least no. of subarrays from the list(l2) which in total have the maximum number of elements from the original list(l1). Subarrays element (Answer) should not be more than L1 element, which Means if 2 is repeated 2 times in L1, so in answer including all subarrays count of 2 can't be more than 2.

Example-1

L1 = [2,3,5,6] 
L2 = [[3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [3, 5], [5, 6], [2, 3, 6]]

The answer for the above example is [[2, 6], [3, 5]]

Example-2

L1 = [2,3,5,6] 
L2 = [[3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [5, 6], [2, 3, 6]]

The answer for the above example is [[2, 3, 6]]

I tried the below approach, but it is taking time due to res_comb since it will have lots of combinations if the length of res is more, let's assume 40. I need something which is much faster.

```py
def return_similar(res,search):  
    res_comb = [list(map(list,combinations(res,i))) for i in range(1,len(res)+1)]
    dict_search = defaultdict(int)
    for x in search:
        dict_search[x]+=1
    match = []
    maxs=0
    for x in res_comb:
        for val in x:
            final_res = []
            for inner in val:
                final_res.extend(inner)
            dict_final_res = defaultdict(int)
            for x in final_res:
                dict_final_res[x]+=1
            count=0
            counter=0
            for x in set(final_res):
                if dict_search[x]<dict_final_res[x]:
                    counter=1
                    break
            if counter==0:
                count = len(final_res)
                if count>maxs:
                    maxs=count
                    match.clear()
                    match.append(val)
                elif (count==maxs) and (count!=0) :
                    match.append(val)
                    
    return match
```

Comment: Updated my approach.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I assume `combinations` if from `itertools`? If yes, please do include `from itertools import combinations` in your code. See also [mre] for more tips on what to include in the code you share.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Focusing on example 1, can you explain why each element of `L2` is included or not included in the desired output?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Hey, We want an output such as if we put all the output elements in a single list, It should be the same or a subset of L1. Example : [[2, 6], [3, 5]] this will be as [2,6,3,5] which is exactly the same as L1.

Comment: What is the expected output for `L1 = [1, 2, 3]` and `L2 = [[1], [2,3], [1,2], [3]]`?

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem Output will be either [[1,2],[3]] or [[2,3],[1]]. Both can be correct.

Comment: This is the [**maximum weighted independent set** problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)). You are looking for an independent set: a set of lists that don't overlap. And you want this set to have "maximum weight", where each list has weight equal to its length. Sadly, this problem is NP-hard, and hard to approximate. A much easier problem is the "maximal independent set" problem, which gives an approximate solution (albeit not necessarily a good one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can easily be reduced to **maximum weight independent set**, where:

- the vertices are the lists in L2;
- two lists share an edge if they have at least one element in common;
- the weight of a list is its length.

Sadly, the maximum independent set problem is NP-hard, and hard to approximate.

A much easier problem is **maximal independent set**. A solution to **maximal independent set** problem is an approximate solution for **maximum independent set**, although not necessarily a good one.

Finding a **maximal independent set** with module networkx:

```py
from networkx import Graph
from networkx import maximal_independent_set
from itertools import combinations

L2 =  [[3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [5, 6], [2, 3, 6]]
vertices = [frozenset(u) for u in L2]

G = Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(vertices)
G.add_edges_from((u,v) for u,v in combinations(vertices, 2) if u.intersection(v))

mis = maximal_independent_set(G)

print(mis)
# [frozenset({3}), frozenset({5, 6})]
```

As you can see, the algorithm found [{3}, {5,6}], which is suboptimal: [{2,5}, {3,6}] would have been better.

Note that `networkx.maximal_independent_set` uses a randomized algorithm: you could run it several times, and keep the best solution found.

### Resources

- [networkx.maximal_independent_set](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.mis.maximal_independent_set.html);
- [dwave_networkx.maximum_weighted_independent_set](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/projects/dwave-networkx/en/latest/reference/algorithms/generated/dwave_networkx.maximum_weighted_independent_set.html);
- [Python libraries for exact weighted maximum independent set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265041/python-libraries-for-exact-weighted-maximum-independent-sets);
- [Heuristic to find the maximum weight independent set in an arbritary graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921996/heuristic-to-find-the-maximum-weight-independent-set-in-an-arbritary-graph)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the approach, I have a doubt: what if there are duplicate elements in the sublist of list, Ex : [[3], [2, 5], [2, 6], [5, 5, 6], [2, 3,3, 6]]. This can be the case when L1 has duplicate elements, so the sub-list can also have it.

Comment: @ShubhamRaj So if L1=[2,2,5,6], then you would want to allow [[2, 5], [2, 6]] as a solution?

Comment: @ShubhamRaj In that case, we should consider multisets instead of sets, and replace the condition `if u.intersection(v)` by `if u+v > l1`, where u, v and l1 have been converted to collections.Counter (the python class for multisets).

Comment: So if L1=[2,2,5,6], then you would want to allow [[2, 5], [2, 6]] as a solution? -> No.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got a solution after having some changes.