# Best algorithm to solve this array problem?

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm

If the for the input, I had a list of lists like so

```
[[2,1], [1,3], [4,5], [6,8], [4,7]]
```

How could I find a/the largest subset such that there are no duplicate/shared elements at all?

For this example, an answer would be

```
[2,1], [4,5], [6,8]
```

or

```
[1,3], [6,8], [4,7]
```

but an invalid answer would be

```
[2,1],[1,3],[4,5]
```

since 1 appears twice here.

My current approach is a recursive approach that uses the idea that either I choose the first element or I don't choose the first element while building the subset but this approach seems way too slow.

What I have: Currently it only returns the size of the largest subset rather than the actual subset but it should be easy to get that once the size is working

```
def disjointSets(allSets):
    maxCount = 0
    used = set()
    def findDisjoint(currCount, arr):
        nonlocal maxCount
        if not arr:
            maxCount = max(maxCount, currCount)
            return
        elif arr[0][0] in used or arr[0][1] in used:
            findDisjoint(currCount, arr[1:])
            return
        else:
            used.add(arr[0][0])
            used.add(arr[0][1])
            findDisjoint(currCount + 1, arr[1:])
            used.clear()
            findDisjoint(currCount, arr[1:])
        return
    findDisjoint(0, allSets)
    return maxCount
```

Comment: Show us what you have done

Comment: This is one of the variants of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: Do the inner lists always have exactly two values?

Comment: @mozway Which one, and what's the optimal time complexity?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes always 2 values

Comment: @PSR Edited with what I have right now

Comment: Then it sounds like [Maximum cardinality matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching).

Comment: Your `disjointSets([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[1,3],[2,4]])` prints `4`, oh-oh...

Comment: I'd actually say it sounds more like [Maximum Set Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing)

Comment: Shorter failure example: `disjointSets([[1,2],[3,4],[1,3],[2,4]])` returns `3`.

Comment: @Dillon Davis Only if you ignore that the size of all sets is 2.

Comment: This sounds exactly like [maximum independent set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding minimum no. of sub-list from the list(l2) which have maximum elements in a other list(l1). Answer should contain least no. of sub-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70662965/finding-minimum-no-of-sub-list-from-the-listl2-which-have-maximum-elements-in)

Comment: @Stef No, doesn't sound like that.

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is a graph -- numbers are vertices, and pairs of numbers are edges.

Your problem is to find the largest set of independent edges (edges that don't share a vertex).

This is usually called a maximum matching, and that is a well known problem with well known solutions.  The [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) is the simplest practical way that is guaranteed to find the best answer.

Comment: Thanks! I looked into it it makes sense now. Suppose I wanted to extend the problem and make it so that each of the elements of the array now have 3 elements like [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], etc].  Would it still be possible with a similar approach?

Comment: I don't know of a similar approach that would work for triples

Answer (score 1):

As @MattTimmermans says, what you have here is an undirected graph where each number is a node and each pair is an edge. A matching is a set of edges that don't share nodes and your job is to find the maximum matching, i.e. a matching that contains the maximum number of edges.

There's a Python package called [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) that deals with networks, in particular, graphs. There's a method in it called [`max_weight_matching`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.matching.max_weight_matching.html) that implements Edmonds' blossom algorithm.

In your example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[2,1], [1,3], [4,5], [6,8], [4,7]])
out = nx.max_weight_matching(G)
```

Output:

```
{(8, 6), (4, 7), (1, 3)}
```